pd.to_datetime in Temporal activity causes bus error in Docker container
When I run this activity in a Docker container, it logs "step 1" but crashes with a bus error before logging "step 2". The issue seems to be caused by the pd.to_datetime call. Here’s the error screenshot:
@activity.defn(name=f"{__name__}.date_time_conversion")
def get_datetimes() -> None:
    
    logger.info("step 1")
    date = pd.to_datetime("2021-01-01")
    logger.info(f"Date: {date}")

    logger.info("step 2")
   

I've ensured that the pandas library is correctly installed in the container. The activity runs fine locally but fails only in the container.
What could be causing pd.to_datetime to fail in this setup? Any ideas on how to resolve this?

"crashes with a bus error" Can you provide the error message, and traceback, if applicable? Do you mean that this is crashing with SIGBUS?
